# Why is this code giving SIGABRT with openMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

```
for (int i = 0; i < x_res; i++){ 
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < y_res; j++) {
        Ray hit = s.kd_tree->intersect(rays[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Why is this code not working in parallel? I cannot find the reason.

The backtrace outputs this:

```
#0  0x00007fff8ce03bf2 in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1  0x00007fff8cd331a1 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2  0x00000001000027e4 in gomp_barrier_destroy ()
#3  0x000000010000247b in gomp_team_end ()
```

Comment: The answer will be somewhere in code you are not showing. One of the worker threads is probably aborting with an error.

Comment: Without being executed in parallel it works well. In the intersect function there is no openMP code.

Comment: So the broad answer mostly likely is that the intersect function isn't thread safe.

Comment: You're crashing inside the pthread implementation; that smells like memory corruption.  Time for `valgrind`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Download the last gcc (4.8 for now) from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ .

The bug with OpenMP is fixed there